# jQuery Clone not copying option values

Tags: jquery, clone

I want to clone an HTML table row and dynamically add a new row to the end of the table using jQuery. This row has a number of dropdown controls. I am trying to clone the row. Most of the controls get copied, but the values of options don't get copied. So I tried to explicitly set the option values. That too did not work.

```
//original table row and its clone
var $tr = $("tr.RowToBeCopied").last();
var $clone = $tr.clone();

var originalSelects = $tr.find("select");
    $(originalSelects).each(function (i) {
        var select = this;
        var originalOptions = $(select).find("option");

        $(originalOptions).each(function (j) {
            var originalOption = this;
            $($clone.find("select").eq(i))
                .find("option").eq(j)
                    .val($(originalOption).val());
        });
    });

$tr.after($clone);
```

I tried setting it as attribute by the following code ->

```
var originalSelects = $tr.find("select");
    $(originalSelects).each(function (i) {
        var select = this;
        var originalOptions = $(select).find("option");

        $(originalOptions).each(function (j) {
            var originalOption = this;
            $($clone.find("select").eq(i))
                .find("option").eq(j)
                    .attr("title", $(originalOption).val());
        });
    });
```

Here, 'title' attribute gets set correctly. But if I change 'title' to 'value', value is not set.

Can somebody please suggest a way to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
var $tr = $("tr.RowToBeCopied").last();
$tr.clone().insertAfter($tr);
```

`clone` performs a deep copy of all elements and text nodes, you don't have to reset the values. Here is an example. http://jsfiddle.net/8bhfR/.